# Pivot outputs two values

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2014

```
create table #Contact(
 LoanNumber int,
 ContactType varchar(10),
 CompanyName varchar(10),
 CompanyPhone varchar(10),
 CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (LoanNumber,ContactType)
)

Insert into #Contact
values (1,'Appriaser','Yige King','11' ),
       (1,'AssetOwner','gqqnbig','22' )
```

This is my table. ContactTypes are only Appriaser and AssetOwner.

[image]

Can I get a table like

```
LoanNumber  AppraiserCompanyName    AppraiserCompanyPhone   AssertOwnerCompanyName  AssertOwnerCompanyPhone
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6103339     YigeKing                11                      gqqnbig                 22
```

I managed to write this

```
select LoanNumber,
        CompanyNamePT.Appriaser as AppriaserCompanyName, CompanyNamePT.AssetOwner as AssetOwnerCompanyName
        --CompanyPhonePT.Appriaser as AppriaserCompanyPhone, CompanyPhonePT.AssetOwner as AssetOwnerCompanyPhone
from  (
    select #contact.LoanNumber, #contact.ContactType, #contact.CompanyName
    from #contact
) as c
pivot ( max(c.CompanyName) for c.ContactType in (Appriaser,AssetOwner)) as CompanyNamePT
--pivot ( max(c.CompanyPhone) for c.ContactType in ([Appriaser],[AssetOwner])) as CompanyPhonePT
```

It outputs company names, but if I uncomment the two lines to get phone number, it throws syntax error.

How can I make it work? Ideally I want to use pivot because I'm learnig it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the desired PIVOT**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select C.LoanNumber
              ,B.*
         From  #Contact C
         Cross Apply ( values (IIF(ContactType='Appriaser'  ,'AppraiserCompanyName' , 'AssetOwnerCompanyName') ,C.CompanyName)
                             ,(IIF(ContactType='Appriaser' , 'AppraiserCompanyPhone', 'AssetOwnerCompanyPhone'),C.CompanyPhone)
                     ) B (Item,Value)
      ) A
pivot ( max(A.Value) for A.Item in ([AppraiserCompanyName],[AppraiserCompanyPhone],[AssetOwnerCompanyName],[AssetOwnerCompanyPhone]) ) P
```

**But a Conditional Aggregation would do as well**

```
Select C.LoanNumber
      ,AppraiserCompanyName   =  max(case when ContactType='Appriaser'  then C.CompanyName end)
      ,AppraiserCompanyPhone  =  max(case when ContactType='Appriaser'  then C.CompanyPhone end)
      ,AssetOwnerCompanyName  =  max(case when ContactType='AssetOwner' then C.CompanyName end)
      ,AssetOwnerCompanyPhone =  max(case when ContactType='AssetOwner' then C.CompanyPhone end)
From #Contact C
Group By C.LoanNumber
```

**Both Would Return**

[image]

**If it Helps with the Visualization, the sub-query with the Cross Apply Generates**

[image]

Comment: a side question, how can I fully qualify LoanNumber? I tried to do `c.LoanNumber`, but it doesnt' work..

Comment: I mean in `select LoanNumber,`, why can't I write `select c.LoanNumber`?

Comment: @LoveRight You can Select A.LoanNumber   I assigned an alias of A, but it is a small matter to change to C.  One moment

Comment: Nice! The max approach is even faster than pivot!

Comment: @LoveRight keep in mind that pivot is expecting X Y and Value. So in the pivot approach we need to UNPIVOT the data first. This has a cost. That said Pivot still has a place in my toolbox